# value of another object as value in another associative array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I have an array called xyz containing keys a and b.
I want to input these into another array as follows :

```
seats =[{ 
        name : xyz.a.
        address: xyz.b}];
```

however the xyz.a is being stored as an object and not by it's value in seats.name and prints undefined when i use console.log

I want to store xyz.a by its value such that seats.name gives the value stored in xyz.a

Comment: To read it, you should do `seats[0].name` (assuming the syntax errors are typos). Or use `seats = {name: xyz.a, address: xyz.b};`

Comment: @Oriol It reads undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript doesn't have variable references or aliases. When you assign a variable to another variable or object, it gets its value at the time of the assignment, it doesn't keep a link to the original location.

If you want something that always gets the current value of a variable, you have to use a function:

```
seats = [ {
    name: function() { return xyz.a; },
    address: function() { return xyz.b; }
}];
```

Then you would call the function to get what you want:

```
seats[0].name();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `xyz` is an object like

```
var xyz = {
    a: 'foo',
    b: 'bar'
};
```

Then, you can use

```
var seats = { 
    name: xyz.a,
    address: xyz.b
};
```